# I'm trying to get alloc init and nil to work within a method in ObjC

Tags: objective-c

should hopefully be an easy question (teaching myself Objective C as I go).

I would like to send a method to an object (Cell) which returns a different object (Waste), and then deletes the reciever (Cell).  Here is what I'm looking at so far:

```
#import "Cell.h"
#import "Waste.h"

@implementation Cell
@synthesize.......
other methods.....

// Send a method to an instance of class "Cell", causing a new object of 
// class "Waste" to be made, then causing the Cell instance to "die"

- (Waste *) die {
    // Create a new object, "newWaste", of class Waste
    // ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'alloc'
    Waste *newWaste = [[Waste alloc] init];
    // Set the energy of "newWa" to 10% what the Cell's energy is
    newWaste.wasteEnergy = (0.1 * cellEnergy);

    // Set the X coordinate of "r" to the Cell's X coordinate
    newWaste.wasteXCoordinate = cellXCoordinate;

    // Set the Y coordinate of "r" to the Cell's Y coordinate
    newWaste.wasteYCoordinate = cellYCoordinate;

    // Variable saying if the Waste is to be excreted set to "NO"
    newWaste.wasteExcreted = NO;

    // Return the new waste object
    return newWaste;

    // Have the Cell "die"  ARC Semantic Issue: 
    // Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family
    self = nil;
}
```

I've put the two issues that come up behind the comments so you know where the problems are, but they're:
**ARC Semantic Issue: No known class method for selector 'alloc'**
and
**ARC Semantic Issue: Cannot assign to 'self' outside of a method in the init family**

Could someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?  I had thought it was straightforward to do:
Class *newInstance = [[Class alloc] init];
and that this could be done inside a method so you can return the instance.  And I had read that self = nil; was the normal way for releasing objects with ARC.

Comment: No that's not how it should be done.  Create a new object (`Waste`) and allocate it as normal (`Waste *waste = [[Waste alloc] init];`).  If `Waste` needs attributes of `Cell` in order to work, then pass an instance of `Cell` to a custom `init` method of `Waste`.  Having an instance "die" isn't normally important at all; simply assign `nil` to any reference to the instance and ARC will do the rest.

Comment: First answer "what does the return statement do?" ...

Comment: You probably want to show the `@interface` for `Waste`.